# Linq AddRange() for objects derived from interface

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to get results using LINQ in WPF on Visual Studio 2015 using Entity Framework 6 (EF). The results need to appear in one `ListView` for the employee's tests. I have two EF entities: `DrugTests` and `AlcoholTests`. In my project, I have some view models to map these to: `DrugTestViewModel` and `AlcoholTestViewModel`, both derived from the interface `ITestViewModel`.

The two VMs share many properties while also having their own unique ones (hence the need for two entities). I'm  using LINQ to return a `Task<ObservableCollection<ITestViewModel>>`, first fetching from the `DrugTests` entity:

```
var query = (from dt in context.DrugTests 
            .Where(x => x.employeeID.Equals(employeeId))
            select new DrugTestViewModel
            {
                EmployeeId = dt.employeeID,
                TestType = "Drug",
                OrderedDate = dt.orderedDate,
                // set other properties
            } 
).ToList();
```

Then I try to add to the query using this:

```
query.AddRange(from at in context.AlcoholTests
                   .Where(x => x.employeeID.Equals(employeeId))
               select new AlcoholTestViewModel
               {
                   EmployeeId = at.employeeID,
                   TestType = "Alcohol",
                   // set other properties...
               }
    );
```

It gives the following exception on the `AddRange()`:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   `'System.Linq.IQueryable<MySolution.ViewModel.AlcoholTestViewModel>'` to
>   `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MySolution.ViewModel.DrugTestViewModel>'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your problem lies in the fact that `query` is a `List<DrugTestViewModel>` and you are trying to add `AlcoholTestViewModel` to it.

Comment: Try replacing `ToList()` with `ToList<ITestViewModel>()`

Comment: Thanks, @IvanStoev. That fixed it! Do you mind throwing that into an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: @Alex To be honest, I didn't mind, but once you kindly asked :)

Comment: @IvanStoev Just wanted to help your reputation plus help others notice the answer better :)

Comment: @Alex Which I greatly appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `query` variable type is `List<DrugTestViewModel>` while you need it to be of type `List<ITestViewModel>`. Since `IQueryable<T>` is covariant, you can achieve that by simply specifying explicitly the desired type when calling `ToList` like this

```
var query = (...).ToList<ITestViewModel>();
```

Comment: Thanks, @IvanStoev. What does `covariant` mean in this context?

Comment: It means that, well you can treat `IQueryable<DerivedClass>` as `IQueryable<BaseClassOrInterface>`.

Answer (score 2):

A little late but I would like to share this another solution. I would use [Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351755(v=vs.110).aspx) this way:

```
var query=...
var query2=..
var result= query.AsEnumerable<ITestViewModel>().Concat(query2);
```

This way you maintain deferred execution in case you don't need to materialize the result yet.

Comment: Interesting idea. But `Cast` throws "*LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.*" so it should be `AsQueryable`. Which also throws exception if the two concrete classes have different fields - "*DbUnionAllExpression requires arguments with compatible collection ResultTypes.*" :(

Comment: yes, after published it I was thinking about that, if both query were not projecting the same columns. I think this solution need to call `AsEnumerable`. Thanks @IvanStoev

Comment: You can remove `Cast` and use simply `AsEnumerable<ITestViewModel>()`. Which will end up with the deferred version of my answer :)

Comment: Agree with this approach. Respect for immutability == safer code.

Answer (score 0):

The from at in context... is a query hence the IQuerable error
Adding .ToList() call ad the end of your linq query returns a list that supports IEnumerable.

Your first code snippet contains the .ToList() your second is missing.

Comment: Better to use `AsEnumerable` and avoid creating an intermediate list.

Comment: Thanks, @juharr. Please see update to the exception. It won't give me the option for `ToList()` on the second query; has `.ToString()` but no `ToList()`

Comment: @Alex Did you put parenthesizes around your query?

Comment: @juharr, yes, but it still wouldn't show `ToList()`.

Comment: @Alex, Well it really doesn't matter since the real issue is that `query` is a list of `DrugTestViewModel` and you cannot add `AlcoholTestViewModel ` to it.  Try Ivan's suggestion.